# Laravel: prevent updated_at from filling on record creation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In recent versions of Laravel >=5.8 I've noticed when you create a new model record, the column `updated_at` from table is filled automatically with the same value as `created_at`. While it makes sense to fill in `created_at` on `Model::create()` what's the point of filling `updated_at` as well? In my view it would make more sense to leave it `NULL` as it was before Laravel 5.8

Is there a known easy way to disable this new behaviour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I personally prefer the current behaviour with `updated_at` set to the current timestamp on creation. In that way, the unmodified records will be placed between the modified ones when sorting by `updated_at`.
If the initial value of `updated_at` was `null`, they would be placed either on the beginning or the end of the list. I don't think that's what most people want.

However, you may change that in the model's class:

```
protected static function booted(): void
{
    static::creating(function (self $model) {
        $model->updated_at = null;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if it was created, it was also the last time the model was updated. It's default Laravel behavior.  You can disable it and write your own on create / update methods for your model if you prefer. However I would keep it and question why it's causing a problem with your logic/ functionality.

```
//your model
public $timestamps = false;

// boot
static::creating( function ($model) {
    $model->setCreatedAt($model->freshTimestamp());
});

//static::updating() .... and so on
```

Comment: If it was created and updated == null, that means the record was only created and not updated. While I understand Laravel's logic, I don't see the point in having to retrieve both `created_at` and `updated_at` to check if a record was ever touched after creation (which happens to be my App's case) - it's data waste.

Comment: They I highly recommend turning off timestamps and using the //boot static methods to control what happens to the created_at and updated_at fields when creating , updating etc.